# Build a docker image from an image built from a subsequent job

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am attempting to build two images, one which contains tools, the other which uses the tools. The one which contains the tools is not pushed to any repository. The tool image should be built in a separate job for reasons which are out of scope of this question.

I have determined Docker already [has this use-case documented](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/share-image-jobs/). But this only seems to work when using the Docker image within a `run` task. I would like to use the Docker image from another `docker/build-push-action@v2` task. For example, the second image pulls in the tools using the `COPY from=...` directive.

---

Here are the files to reproduce the issue...

Tool Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN touch /tools
```

Uses tools Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
COPY --from=tools:latest /tools /
```

These are in a git repository which is like this...

```
.
├── tools
│   └── Dockerfile
└── uses-tools
    └── Dockerfile
```

Github Actions workflow:

```yaml
name: Build images
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-tools:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Build tools image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          tags: tools:latest
          context: tools
          load: true
          outputs: type=docker,dest=/tmp/tools.tar

      - name: Upload tools image as artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: tools-image
          path: /tmp/tools.tar

  build-uses-tools:
    needs: build-tools
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Download tools image artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with: 
          name: tools-image
          path: /tmp

      - name: Load tools image artifact
        run: |
          docker load --input /tmp/tools.tar
          docker image ls -a

      - name: Build uses tools image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          load: true
          context: uses-tools
```

---

I have tried the `load` key with the `docker/build-push-action@v2` and it does not seem to change anything.

I have tried doing the same 2nd build within the same job as the first tool image build, and this also does not work; even if it did it doesn't answer the question, I guess.